# Simple unit converter in Python

Tags: python, converters, units-of-measurement

I am new to programming and I am trying to make a simple unit converter in python. I want to convert units within the metric system and metric to imperial and vice-versa. I have started with this code and I found this method is slow and in-efficient, How can I code this more efficiently?

```
import math
import time
"""Unit Converter"""
#variable setting
cat = raw_input ("Which category would you like to convert? we support length(l) and Weight(w):  ")
if cat == ("l"):
unit1 = raw_input ("Which unit would you like to convert from: ")
unit2 = raw_input ("Which unit would you like to convert to: ")
num1 = raw_input ("Enter your value: " )
    
    ##Calculations  
    
if unit1 == "cm" and unit2 == "m":
    ans = float(num1)/100       
elif unit1 == "mm" and unit2 == "cm":
    ans = float(num1)/10
elif unit1 == "m" and unit2 == "cm":
    ans = float(num1)*100
elif unit1 == "cm" and unit2 == "mm":
    ans = float(num1)*10
elif unit1 == "mm" and unit2 == "m":
    ans = float(num1)/1000
elif unit1 == "m" and unit2 == "mm":
    ans = float(num1)*1000  
elif unit1 == "km" and unit2 == "m":
    ans = float(num1)*1000
elif unit1 == "m" and unit2 == "km":
    ans = float(num1)/1000
elif unit1 == "mm" and unit2 == "km":
    ans = float(num1)/1000000
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question is about improving working code. It would be more fit to [codereview.se].

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks, I will post on there, I didn't even know that existed.

Comment: Do you mean it was slow to write?

Comment: @PeterWood Yes, once I have done all combinations this would take a very long time. I was also hoping to add weight, speed, energy and data storage.

Comment: For future notice, if you'd like your question moved to another SE site, you can flag it for moderation and request that it be moved to the desired new site.

Comment: I think a dictionary of dictionaries would be your best bet here. If you're posting to CodeReview I could write up what I'm thinking as an answer over there.

Comment: You might be interested in [Pint: a Python units library](http://pint.readthedocs.org/en/0.6/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use a dictionary with conversion factors, and a function that calls them.

```
def convert_si(val: float, unit_in: str, unit_out: str) -> float:
    SI = {'mm': 0.001, 'cm': 0.01, 'm': 1.0, 'km': 1000.0}
    return val * SI[unit_in] / SI[unit_out]
```

**Example:**

```
>>> convert_si(1, 'm', 'km')
0.001
>>> convert_si(1, 'km', 'm')
1000.0
>>> convert_si(1, 'cm', 'm')
0.01
```

Comment: Thanks, This is kind of what I was thinking but I wasn't quite sure on how.

Comment: Himanshu's suggestion could be good for more complex problems; though, I think you could generalize this further to US customary units using another dictionary of conversion factors for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

## All standard unit conversions (kilo, hecto, deka, base, deci, centi, milli)

Updated @ryanjdillon's answer to support any of the following conversions:

```
convert_si(10, 'kilograms', 'grams')
convert_si(5, 'liter', 'kiloliters')
convert_si(6, 'millimeter', 'meter')
convert_si(1, 'kilo', '') # no need to specify type of measurement
convert_si(4, 'hectometer', 'kilometer')
convert_si(7, 'hecto', 'deka') # no need to specify type of measurement
convert_si(3, 'hectogram', 'decigram')
convert_si(2, 'centiliter', 'kiloliter')
convert_si(2, 'centimeter') # without the 3rd argument converts to base unit
```

Here is the code:

```
def clean_units(unit):
    unit = unit.rstrip('s')  # remove plural
    words_to_remove = ['meter', 'liter', 'gram']  # remove type of unit
    for word in words_to_remove:
        unit = unit.replace(word, '')
    return unit

def convert_si(val, unit_in, unit_out=''):
    SI = {'milli': 0.001, 'centi': 0.01,
          'deci': 0.1, '': 1.0, 'deka': 10,
          'hecto': 100, 'kilo': 1000}

    unit_in = clean_units(unit_in)
    unit_out = clean_units(unit_out)
    return val*SI[unit_in]/SI[unit_out]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary with this example.

```
def handle_one():
  print 'one'

def handle_two():
  print 'two'

def handle_three():
  print 'three'

print 'Enter 1 for handle_one'
print 'Enter 2 for handle_two'
print 'Enter 3 for handle_three'
choice=raw_input()
{
'1':  handle_one,
'2':  handle_two,
'3':  handle_three,
}.get(choice)()
```

Answer (score 0):

For those happy to use an external package, [Axiompy](https://github.com/ArztKlein/Axiompy) is an option.

Installation: `pip install axiompy`

```py
from axiompy import Units
units = Units()
print(units.unit_convert(3 * units.metre, units.foot))
>>> <Value (9.84251968503937 <Unit (foot)>)>
```