# How to convert string value like "4w 2d.." to timedelta?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have incoming string data in format like "`4w 2d 5h`" (weeks(w), days(d), hours(h), minutes(m)), some it can have different number of parameters (from 1 to 4, e.g "`1w`", "`2w 5h`", "`3w 1d 5h 3m`", etc).
I need to convert it to timedelta (datetime) format.
The only way I know it is to split it and then use statements depending on the letter. But probably there is more efficient way?

Comment: You will need some sort of splitting and some sort of statements, yes. No magic way to avoid that. You can maybe look for a library that already implements that if you don’t want to write it yourself.

Comment: Basically identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091117/simple-unit-converter-in-python -- in brief, create a dictionary which maps the suffixes you want to convert to a function or symbol which handles this particular unit. `timedelta` already lets you specify different units so basically just convert your input to a dictionary of keyword arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure the strings are well formatted then you could try to use `re`:

```py
import re
from datetime import timedelta

re_td = re.compile(r"(\d+)(w|d|h|m)")
units = {"w": "weeks", "d": "days", "h": "hours", "m": "minutes"}

def to_timedelta(string):
    return timedelta(**{units[u]: int(val) for val, u in re_td.findall(string)})
```

The pattern `(\d+)(w|d|h|m)` looks for numbers followed by one of the allowed letters, and due to the grouping a match in `.findall` packs them into a tuple. If there could be whitespace between the number and the letter then use `(\d+)\s*(w|d|h|m)` instead.